# Centered gravity moves radio button description, not button itself

Tags: android, android-layout

In the XML to follow, each `RadioButton` is set to `android:gravity="center"`.

All three buttons show up, but the button descriptions are centered. The buttons themselves are not. How do I center the buttons as well as their descriptions?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this picture, you can ignore the top bar. That's already been coded in. What I'm seeing is the RadioButtons far to the right of the "RadioButton" text (the button itself is up against the layout bounds). The desired end result is, since I can't post images: [Here it is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvWqs.png)

Comment: can you give a screenshot of what you want the final outcome to be

Comment: I believe you want layout_gravity instead of gravity.

Comment: Setting android:layout_gravity="center" caused the buttons to gravitate to the left.

Comment: so you want each radio button and its description in one line?

Comment: I hope that I understood you correctly. try using gravity:center|left for radio button

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have tried editing your layout to do what is in your screenshot. I don't think this is an efficient way to do this but this is the only way that worked for me.

I inserted every radiobutton inside a parent linerlayout, and then used gravity center.

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RadioGroup>
```

I really hope there's a better solution than this. But here, hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me! The LinearLayout may be useful when not only radio button but for example text should be displayed below the radio button.

Comment: This does work. I would only suggest using a FrameLayout instead of a LinearLayout, since there is only one child. Easier for Android to inflate.

Comment: Now that you have written RadioButton inside LinearLayout, they won't be considered as RadioGroup's child. So there's no use of RadioGroup. You have to manage each RadioButton separately

Answer (score 0):

Just add widget.Space in between, so the entire widget.RadioButton will get shifted to right...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
</RadioGroup>
```